# How to check whether a sheet exists or not using excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any excel function to check whether a sheet exists or not?

Comment: No, you'll need to use VB See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040454/7154977

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a specific function but you can build it from others:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")))
```

Returns `TRUE` if Sheet2 exists otherwise `FALSE`.

If your sheet name is in another cell, such as `B1`, you could use:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(INDIRECT(B1&"!A1")))
```